# SQL Join query to join 2 tables to get desired output

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables and need to join them to get a desired result. I tried multiple types of joins but no luck.
Please assist.Below is how my tables looks like:

**select * from t1**

```
ProductId, Sequence, Property
100, 1, Size
100, 2, Folder
100, 3, License
101, 1, Usage
101, 2, Duration
```

**select * from t2**

```
SrNo, ProductId, Property, PropertyValue
1,    100, Size, 10GB
2,    100, Folder, /home/path
3,    101, Usage, Database
```

I need to join them to get the following result:

```
SrNo, ProductId, Sequence, Property, PropertyValue
1     100         1         Size      10GB
1     100         2         Folder    
1     100         3         License     
2     100         1         Size      
2     100         2         Folder    /home/path
2     100         3         License   
3     101         1         Usage      Database
3     101         2         Duration
```

Below are the SQLs to reproduce the same tables:

```
create table t1 (ProductId INT, Sequence INT, Property VARCHAR(255))
insert into t1 values(100,1,'Size');
insert into t1 values(100,2,'Folder');
insert into t1 values(100,3,'License');
insert into t1 values(101,1,'Usage');
insert into t1 values(101,2,'Duration');

create table t2 (SrNo INT, ProductId INT, Property VARCHAR(255), PropertyValue VARCHAR(255))
insert into t2 values(1,100,'Size','10GB');
insert into t2 values(2,100,'Folder','/home/path');
insert into t2 values(3,101,'Usage','Database');
```

Please assist how can I write my query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    table2.SrNo,
    table1.ProductId,
    table1.Sequence, 
    table1.Property,
    table2.PropertyValue
FROM t1 AS table1  
JOIN t2 AS table2 ON table1.ProductId = table2.ProductId
```

Comment: It is not showing the same result.This is what it is showing:              1,100,1,Size,10GB
                     2,100,1,Size,/home/path
1,100,2,Folder,10GB
2,100,2,Folder,/home/path,
1,100,3,License,10GB,
2,100,3,License,/home/path,
3,101,1,Usage,Database,
3,101,2,Duration,Database

Comment: Can you provide the table definitions here?

Comment: I have added the table DDLs also

Comment: Primary & Foreign Keys?

Comment: I have kept only that I need for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
SELECT T2.SrNo, T2.ProductId, T1.Sequence, T1.Property, T3.PropertyValue
FROM T2
JOIN T1 ON T2.ProductID = T1.ProductID
LEFT JOIN T2 AS T3 ON T1.Property = T3.Property
```

The "problem" here is that you are treating T2 as two different tables.  When I first select from T2 I'm only selecting SrNo and ProductId to get a list of these "valid" values.  I then join them to T1.  I then join back to T2 treating it as a lookup table for PropertyValue.  Here I use a left join because not all combinations of Property and Sequence have a valid Property.

---

I "fixed" the code above based on the comment but a problem becomes clear.  In your example you show

```
SrNo, ProductId, Sequence, Property, PropertyValue
1     100         1         Size      10GB
2     100         1         Size
```

I don't know why the 2nd row does not have a PropertyValue of 10GB

Comment: I am getting this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'T3.Sequence' in 'on clause'

Comment: I output I am getting is not matching the expected output. Can you please check at your end.

Comment: @sachinv - No.  Now you have to do some work.  You need to show what your starting data is -- what code you are using and what you expect.  AS WRITTEN IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO GET THE RESULTS YOU DESCRIBE. As I say in my edit.